# Example of polynomial which satisfy the conditions

Tags: calculus

Give example of polynomial function $P: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which have local maximu at point $-1$, local minimum at $1$ and satisfy condition $P(-1) < P(1)$.

I tried take any polynomial degree $3$, $4$ and $5$. Then I consider conditions:

$P(-1)<P(1)$,$P'(-1)=0$, $P'(1)=0$, $P''(-1) < 0$, $P''(1) > 0$ but I couldn't find this polynomial.

I have no idea. I will grateful for yours help and hints.

Comment: What does $P'(-1)=0$, $P'(1)=0$ tell you about the polynomial $P'$?

Comment: If you draw a sketch of what this has to look like you will see that you need at least four turning points, so a polynomial of degree at least $5$ (its derivative has four zeros).

Comment: @Chris Eagle I think that $P'(x) = a(x-1)(x+1)Q(x)$

Comment: @Mark Bennet I drew sketch and focused on this task. After all I received polynomial like $\frac{1}{5} x^5 - \frac{5}{12}x^3 + \frac{1}{4}x$. I will grateful if yuo could examine my resolution.

Comment: It seems to do the job. Well done. Why not post an explanation of what you did as an answer (you have clearly chosen particular values for turning points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I took local minimum at $ \frac{-1}{2}$ and $1$, local maximum at $-1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $P'(x) = a(x+1)(x+ \frac{1}{2})(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{2})$. Hence I have $P''(x)$ and $P(x)$.

I would like $P''(-1) < 0$, $P''(1)>0$, $P''(- \frac{1}{2}) > 0$, $P''(\frac{1}{2}) < 0$. Hence $a>0$.

$P(x) = \int_0^x P'(t) dt + C$. Because $P(-1)<P(1)$ we can take $a>0$ and any $ C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer just as you'd "accept" any answer to a question you ask: you can accept *one (and only one)* answer to a question you ask, and we encourage you to do so. To accept an answer, simply click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept: when you click on it, it turns *green*. Bonus: you get $2$ reputation points each time you accept an answer.